# stuck at dollar prompt

Tags: 12.04

I have an Acer laptop and running Ubuntu 12.04. I tried updating it and I then fell asleep and when I woke I tried restarting it. It then asked me to login by this prompt:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS username-laptop tty1

username-laptop login:
```

I logged in and filled the password and I get to this prompt:

```
username@username-laptop:~$
```

So my question is what do I do next?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Ubuntu Desktop, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the desktop GUI.  If this doesn't work, you can either reboot or run `startx` in the prompt.